# Java - Regex to check in password contains special chars; escaping?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I'm writing some unit tests to check passwords are valid and such. One case, is ensuring the passwords contain special chars, one uppercase, one lowercase, and one digit.

I wrote a test using regex to check for special chars such as:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[_]+[!]+[$]+[%]+[\\^]+[&]+[*]+[(]+[)]+[.]+[-]+[+]+");
Matcher m = p.matcher("__!$%%%^^&**().-++");
boolean b = m.matches();


System.out.println(b);
```

I had to escape the ^ (caret symbol) but seemingly no other character - is this correct? I just each input individually and it seems to check correctly, though the syntax seemed a bit more convoluted than I initially intended? is using Regex the best way to achieve this check and the compile method the way I used it ?

I'll take any tips, thank you!

Comment: I would have thought that `$`, `.`, `*` , `-`, `+` would need escaping? Basically everything that has a special regex meaning

Comment: The nice thing about regex is that you can escape any special character, even if it doesn't need to be escaped. You can always test/build your expressions on https://regex101.com

Comment: Yup, I didn't escape anything but the carrot symbol ^, and it seems to worked? Link to regex I used here https://regex101.com/r/aEc8C8/1

Comment: Here's a tip: Get into the habit of Hashing passwords then you wouldn't need to worry about these checks.

Comment: So if you hashed the passwords you wouldn't need to write Unit Tests for them?

Comment: @DevilsHnd , can you point to some articles about Hashing Passwords.

Comment: Unit Testing your methods and or classes is always a good idea so as to ensure they reliably run as intended. What I mean is you wouldn't need to test to ensure that special characters are contained within a password since they really don't gain anything in a Hash since hashing algorithms work with streams of bytes, not with characters. Besides you can always add whatever salt you like if that makes you feel any better. In my opinion, passwords should never be stored as plain text. Passwords should be hashed then immediately destroyed. A hash is compared to another hash for validity.

Comment: @VishwaRatna - If you can't find any information on hashing passwords either through StackOverflow or Google then you need to pick it up a little on your search skills. The information, articles, blogs, how to's, etc are literally everywhere.